# Combining streams with baconjs

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

I have asynchronous events that I need combining. I am constructing an array of N streams; each stream has an onValue function to process the returned data.

I have tried combining all of those streams into one onValues on top of the onValue, but it does not get called properly.

```
var streams = [] 
...
stream = Bacon.fromCallback .... 
stream.onValue...( )

streams.push(stream)

...
Bacon.onValues(streams, f() { .... } )
```

What would be the right way to have a function called back when EACH stream has a (unique) value... AND when everything is completed?

Comment: Sounds to me as if you rather want to use a Promise than a Stream here…

Comment: @bergi how would you do it with a promise

Comment: Instead of `stream` it's `promise`, instead of `Bacon.fromCallback` you'll find something appropriate in the respective library that you use, instead of `onValue` you'd use `then`. And in the end you combine them by `Promise.all(promises).then(f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume this does the job:

```
Bacon.combineAsArray(streams).onEnd(f)
```

Comment: Oh, from the act of accepting the answer I derive it really does :-)

Comment: Indeed it does, that is what we came across on our side